# Reactjs: Calling methods inside and outside of React.createClass block

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, components

Warning -This will sound like the most noob question ever, but I think it is a confusing thing for people trying to process React components initially (or maybe I'm an idiot haha), but I thought this would be a good question for the beginner community.

**So I wanted to demystify a common thing that happens whenever I create a new helper method. I always wonder -should I be putting this inside "React.createClass" block or put it outside of "React.createClass" block.**

Its obvious when it is a method that is part of the component life cycle or a render method, **but I've seen examples helper methods put both inside and outside and it's hard to tell if there is a definitive line(guidelines) for when it is proper to do one or the other.**

Are there guideline principles or cases for a React developer to know which
case it better?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will want to keep your code blocks small enough to see clearly what is happening with that block. So if you have a long helper method then outside is probably better. If you have a lot of helper methods then you may want all of them outside. The basic rule is for your code to be clear and understandable.